# org-mode: Something like bytefield package

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there a way to generate data structure overviews like the [bytefield package for latex](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/bytefield/bytefield.pdf) with plain tables? (I.e. I don't want to fall back to LaTeX)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by a "data structure overview", and what the bytefield package does?